# Cubic spline representation from second derivative

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, spline

I've got a dataset from a paper, where the datapoints x, y and the second derivative y" is given. The authors state that this is used to get a cubic spline representation.

My Question is:

How do I get the spline representation with scipy incorporating the second derivative?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what, exactly, you mean. The very concept of a cubic spline comes from having values of the function and the second derivatives at various points - then you can define the spline going through the points with a continuous second derivative (see any intro to splines). Thus, given y and y'' one can write the spline function. Or, do you want to take the given y and y'' and return the appropriate set of knots for a spline?

Comment: @JonCuster The authors of this paper have measured a lot of data points, and they state that a cubic spline fits them very well. Then they give a table with just a few entries of  x, y, and y'' values stating they represent the cubic spline citing numerical recipes in pascal.

Comment: Of course a cubic spline fits them well - it goes through every point be definition! Now, if they give a table with just 'a few' entries, I would suspect that they imply that those few points are all that are needed to pretty much represent the entire data set. Then, use the definition of cubic splines (and Numerical Recipes certainly has the simple equations) and construct the spline function.

Comment: @JonCuster I think that's the point. You (and I for that matter) just assumed P3trus was talking spline **interpolation**. However, splines are also used for smoothing and curve fitting (in which case it won't go through every data point). The latter seems to match the description. Sadly, I know nothing about this subject, so can't be of any more help.

Comment: @PaulPanzer - That could be quite true upon reflection. In that case, I would take the tabulated values, throw them in to the spline functional form, and compare with the data.

Comment: P3trus cc @JonCuster - actually, there is one thing you could try quickly. Do what I described in my A, to get a spline from your table and once you have it calculate the second derivatives at all the interior nodes and check if they match the table. If they do, you're done.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Already did that, and they don't match.

Answer (score 2):

The authors are almost certainly referring to using the second derivatives at the very *endpoints* of the data.

In cubic spline interpolation once you've specified the values you have 2 degrees of freedom left, indeed: *n* + 1 nodes gives you *n* polynomials with 4 *n* parameters of these you spend *n* + 1 to fit the values and 3 for consistency at each of the *n* - 1 joints, leaving 2.

You can use [scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html); the appropriate boundary condition would be `bc_type=((2, y"0), (2, y"n))` where `y"0` and `y"n` are the second derivatives at the first and last data points.

Comment: Please see my comment to JohnCuster